# How to retrieve folder by ID in a shared drive with Google Drive API v3

Tags: go, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-go-client

I'm trying to retrieve a specific folder based on a driveId and a folderId. I can easily retrieve a folder by its ID if it's in the user's drive like so:

```
folder, err := srv.Files.Get(folderId).Do()
```

If the folderId I pass refers to a folder in a shared drive, then I get a 404 with a message like "googleapi: Error 404: File not found: 1abcdefgh23456789., notFound".

Ideally, I'm looking for something like:

```
folder, err := srv.Files.Get(folderId).DriveId(driveId).Do()
```

But that fails because there's no such function ("srv.Files.Get(folderId).DriveId undefined (type *drive.FilesGetCall has no field or method DriveId").

I've tried to workaround this by using the more complex `List` method:

```
res, err := srv.Files.List().Q("id = '" + folderId + "' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").SupportsAllDrives(true).IncludeItemsFromAllDrives(true).Corpora("drive").DriveId(driveId).Do()
```

But that fails at runtime with "googleapi: Error 400: Invalid Value, invalid". I can use `name = '<my folder name>'` but that's obviously not good because there could be duplicate names.

What is the proper way to get a folder in a shared drive by its ID?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is currently correct. The [Q](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms#operators) parameter for searching is very limited and there is no other way currently to request just the sheared drive.

I suspect what you will need to do is sort though them locally

The [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files) has a field called drive id that you could check.  Make sure that you add it to fields if its not returning as part of your response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### To obtain a file located on a shared Drive, you need to set the parameter `supportsAllDrives` to `true`

See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get).